# sql server 2005 concatenate nvarchar, results sometimes in strange characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, concatenation, collation, nvarchar

I'm experiencing a very strange behavior when concatenating two nvarchar(20) columns with ' - ' into a nvarchar(100), in sql server 2005.
Here's the simplified Update Statement:

```
UPDATE tbl3
SET tbl3.col1 = t1.col1+' - '+t2.col1
FROM 
    tbl1 AS t1
INNER JOIN
    tbl2 AS t2 ON 1=1
INNER JOIN
    tbl3 AS t3
ON
    t3.col2 = t1.col2+t2.col2
;
```

Here are the results for some records (the single quotes are not in the columns, just representing exactly where it starts and ends):

**tbl1.col1**:'Saídos'

**tbl2.col1.1stRow**:'Salário rendim.mens.'

**tbl2.col1.2ndRow**:'Assalariados por mês'

***1st update:***

**tbl3.col1.1stRow**:'Salário rendim.mens.'

**tbl3.col1.2ndRow**:'Saídos - Assalariados por mês'

***2nd upate:***

**tbl3.col1.1stRow**:'Saídos - SalÃ¡rio rendim.mens'

**tbl3.col1.2ndRow**:'Saídos - Assalariados por mÃª'

***3nd upate:***

**tbl3.col1.1stRow**:'Saídos - SalÃ¡rio rendim.mens'

**tbl3.col1.2ndRow**:'Saídos - Assalariados por mÃª'

***4th upate:***

**tbl3.col1.1stRow**:'Saídos - Salário rendim.mens.'

**tbl3.col1.2ndRow**:'Saídos - Assalariados por mÃª'

As said, tbl1.col1 and tbl2.col1 are nvarchar(20), and tbl3.col1 is nvarchar(100)
All the 3 columns have, in table designer, Collation set to , and database Collation is set to Latin1_General_CI_AS.

Any help or troubleshoot is most welcomed, thanks!

Comment: I don't know what is causing this but use Unicode character types if you can. Issues like this one just go away.

Comment: as you suggested, i altered to nvarchar in all tables, still get the same strange behavior...

Comment: Then, the only reason I can think of is "surprising" data (although I cannot think of any way this could happen). Try creating an executable repo on sqlfiddle.com so that we can play with it. I just tried `SELECT N'Salário rendim.mens.' + N'Saídos - Assalariados por mês'` and it works fine.

Comment: Alternative reason: There is still a collation problem or non-unicode data type involved without you noticing it. Creating a repo (by scripting the tables, for example) will let you find the problem.

Comment: AH! Found it, your Unicode suggestion was the right one! I altered the tables to nvarchar but forgot the ' - ', to unicode i just need N' - ' :D It even works if i alter the columns back to varchar.

Comment: I have never seen this class of bug before. Interesting and nasty.

Answer (score 0):

Got it,

The `' - '` needs to be unicode, like `N' - '`:

```
UPDATE tbl3
SET tbl3.col1 = t1.col1+N' - '+t2.col1
FROM 
    tbl1 AS t1
INNER JOIN
    tbl2 AS t2 ON 1=1
INNER JOIN
    tbl3 AS t3
ON
    t3.col2 = t1.col2+t2.col2
;
```

This also works if the columns are varchar (not unicode), but i would advise to use nvarchar allways.